# 415 Unsupported Media Error in PUT method using REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Firstly I would like to say that I am new to development and have started working directly with REST. So I may be stupid to ask some silly questions. Please accept my apologies in advance!

Regarding the Problem - I am trying to learn how REST API WebServices can be developed so I started with a Mavan Project using the Archetype - "**jersey-quickstart-webapp**" and using Chrome **POSTMAN** as the Rest Client.
I am successful in writing GET methods but getting struck while writing PUT.
Every time I get only two things - a) Runtime Exception with 404 error or b) 415 Error with Media unsupported.

I have tried different combinations for `@Consumes` annotation and method parameters like `@FormParam`, `@QueryParam` but no luck. I am neither successful in reading the value sent via PUT to my application from POSTMAN nor I am able to send a simple response back to POSTMAN. Please suggest and drive me a path where I can overcome these small hurdles.

My code -

```
package tcs.suraj.learnwebservices;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import tcs.suraj.learnwebservices.domain.MovieBean;

@Path("/movies")
public class Movies {

    static ArrayList<MovieBean> movieList = new ArrayList<MovieBean>() ;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMovie(){
        System.out.println("Under Construction");    
        return "Under Construction";
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String updateMovie(@FormParam("name") String name){
        Response r ;
        System.out.println(name +" updated!");
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your Postman request. You have enough rep now to post images

Comment: Without the request is hard to answer your question, in any case, consider that prior of using a PUT you need a POST that gives you the ID of the resource. You cannot use PUT on a non existing resource.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Tomcat for deployment, add this to your `web.xml` and then try again.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Note: I have used `org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter` in Tomcat 7.0.53. I am not sure what is the least version supported for `CorsFilter`.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the filter in web.xml but no luck. I am using tomcat 7.0.55.    Please suggest.

Comment: Since you are getting 415 error, it might be an issue with the request. Try changing the PUT request to a simple JSON request (`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`), and send `Content-Type` as `application/json` from Postman. For testing, have only an SOP in your PUT method.